# Range selection programatically in Material Date Picker after single day selection

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

I'm looking for a Datepicker that you can click in one day and it automatically selects all the week programatically. I've tried with Material Datepicker but I didn't found a solution.

OnDateSelected -> Set range from Monday to Sunday, and paint the days in the datepicker.

Is this posible?

Thanks!

val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
.setSelection(androidx.core.util.Pair(MaterialDatePicker.thisMonthInUtcMilliseconds(),
MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()))
.build(

I tried this and it creates my datepicker with range but I want to create a range after the user clicks on a single date.

Comment: So is  this something calendar and you want to customize it ?

Comment: I want to do it with Material Date Picker if posible, if not what can I do to implement what I want? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure about Material date picker library but if you would like to use customized calendars then let me know?